# CSS How to resize an image towards the div

Tags: css

I have a div with a text on the left part of it:

```css
* {padding: 0%;margin: 0%;}
body {background-color: brown;}
.content_box {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: brown;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}
.content_box div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}
.content_box img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 30%;
    /*height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;*/
}
.content_box .credentials {color: beige;}
.content_box .left {margin-left: auto;}
.content_box .right {margin-right: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class='content_box'>
        <div class='left'>
            <div class='credentials'>Username</div>
            <p>Posted message</p>
            <div class='credentials'>01/01/2021</div>
        </div>
        <div class='right'>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to add an image on the right part of it. But it has to be set to the size of text(so if we have three lines of text image will be bigger than if we had one line of text, even if the image with 3 lines is 30x30 pixels, and 1 line text is 1024x1024 pixels)

I would love it if someone could edit my question because I'm not too good at English...

Comment: so you want to resize the image based on the height of left side content. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes! You are right

Comment: I can't understand the question :( If not in English can you descirbe it in Hindi in comment section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position the `.content_box` relative and the `.right` div absolute. So you can give it the height of it's parent. Finally give the image a `max-height` of 100%:

```
    .content_box {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    .right {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: red;
    }
    
    .right img {
        max-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Image is still huge, it doesn't change size of it... At least for me